# What is the difference between extend method for list and update method for set?

Tags: python

Why is it that a set does not have extend() but has update() instead?
What is the reason?

Comment: Those are two methods that do different things to different data structures. I don't get the question.

Comment: unlike `list`, `set` and `dict` are unordered, so I guess `update` is more meaningful than `extend` which suggests directionality

Comment: @mozway also `update` may or may not add elements.

Comment: Yes, very true, as you said different methods, different functions, different names ;)

Comment: @timgeb Meh... even the `add` method may not add.

Answer (score 2):

`extend` augments a list regardless of its existing content whereas `update` uses the existing content in the process, only adding items that are not already there.  Updating a set does not necessarily make it larger (e.g. if you only provide values already in the set) so `extend` would not be an appropriate name. Conversely, `update` would not be appropriate for a list because no processing is performed on the basis of existing content.

This is semantically consistent with the english definitions of these verbs:

**Extend:**  cause to cover a larger area; make longer or wider

**Update:**  make (something) more modern or up to date